# getting incomplete description in RSS feeds

Tags: android, rss

I am fetching "description" tag from RSS feed. But from the logs, I can see description is not coming full. It is indenting, but if i paste the url in browser it will show complete description. Also nowhere in code i am suppressing content. What could be reason and how to get full content ?

```
Once upon a time, a Guru was giving darshan to a congregation. People 
were coming and bowing down, seeking blessings. Gurudev was silent most of the 
time and when somebody would come and share their troubles, looking for a response, 
he would say only one thing. One person came to him and said, “I failed [...]
```

Below is the url for feed :

http://srisriravishankar.org/feed/

Thanks

Editing Question for asatanballa [How to retrive "content:encoded" tag in XML Parser:

RssFeedStructure.java

```
public class RssFeedStructure {

//private long articleId;
//private long feedId;
private String title;
private String description;
private String imgLink;
private String pubDate;

private String link;
private String published;
private String content;
private URL url;
private String encodedContent;

/*public long getArticleId() {
    return articleId;
}

public void setArticleId(long articleId) {
    this.articleId = articleId;
}

public long getFeedId() {
    return feedId;
}


public void setFeedId(long feedId) {
    this.feedId = feedId;
}*/

/**
 * @return the title
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

/**
 * @param title
 *            the title to set
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

/**
 * @return the url
 */
public URL getUrl() {
    return url;
}

/**
 * @param url
 *            the url to set
 */
public void setUrl(URL url) {
    this.url = url;
}

/**
 * @param description
 *            the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;

    /*if (description.contains("<img ")) {
        String img = description.substring(description.indexOf("<img "));
        String cleanUp = img.substring(0, img.indexOf(">") + 1);
        img = img.substring(img.indexOf("src=") + 5);
        int indexOf = img.indexOf("'");
        if (indexOf == -1) {
            indexOf = img.indexOf("\"");
        }
        img = img.substring(0, indexOf);

        this.description = this.description.replace(cleanUp, "");
    }*/
}

/**
 * @return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/**
 * @param pubDate
 *            the pubDate to set
 */
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

/**
 * @return the pubDate
 */
public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

/**
 * @param encodedContent
 *            the encodedContent to set
 */
public void setEncodedContent(String encodedContent) {
    this.encodedContent = encodedContent;
}

/**
 * @return the encodedContent
 */
public String getEncodedContent() {
    return encodedContent;
}

/**
 * @param imgLink
 *            the imgLink to set
 */
public void setImgLink(String imgLink) {
    this.imgLink = imgLink;
}

/**
 * @return the imgLink
 */
public String getImgLink() {
    return imgLink;
}


/**
 * @param link
 *            the pubDate to set
 */
public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

/**
 * @return the pubDate
 */
public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

/**
 * @param content
 *            the pubDate to set
 */
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

/**
 * @return the pubDate
 */
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

/**
 * @param published
 *            the pubDate to set
 */
public void setPublished(String published) {
    this.published = published;
}

/**
 * @return the pubDate
 */
public String getPublished() {
    return published;
}

}
```

XmlHandler.java

```
public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private RssFeedStructure feedStr = new RssFeedStructure();
private List<RssFeedStructure> rssList = new ArrayList<RssFeedStructure>();

private int articlesAdded = 0;

// Number of articles to download
private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 55;

StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) {
    chars = new StringBuffer();

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure"))

    {
        if (!atts.getValue("url").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            feedStr.setImgLink(atts.getValue("url").toString());
        } else {
            feedStr.setImgLink("");
        }
    }

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        feedStr.setTitle(chars.toString());
    } 

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
       feedStr.setDescription(chars.toString());
    } 

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
       feedStr.setPubDate(chars.toString());
    } 

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("encoded")) {
       feedStr.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    } 

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("published")) {
           feedStr.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    }

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("content")) {
           feedStr.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    }

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
           feedStr.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    }

    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content"))
    {
    } 

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
    }


    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        rssList.add(feedStr);

        feedStr = new RssFeedStructure();
        articlesAdded++;
        if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT) {
            throw new SAXException();
        }
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}

public List<RssFeedStructure> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        url = new URL(feedUrl);
        xr.setContentHandler(this);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (SAXException e) {

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

    }

    return rssList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came to know that SAX Parser don't fetch tags like "content:encoded" from RSS Feed. You can use DOM parser instead of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another else section but look for "content:encoded". I believe just "content" will not work based on the tags I saw.

```
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")) {
       feedStr.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
}
```

-- Original answer for thread --

That is normally under control of the generator of the feed, not you as the consumer of the feed. In configuring the RSS feed for say, a blog, the owner decides to either include the entire text or to include only some subset as an abstract. Some feed owners may do the subset to have you actually visit the site rather than just have you consumer the feed.

Comment: any third party libraries to fetch the complete description ?

Comment: I font believe so. The problem is not the fetching software. The problem is that it's just plain not in the feed.

Comment: No....Its not that...If you paste the same link in browser it will show complete description. However in RSS feed if the description is half then it will really show the half description

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood? The link you shared (http://srisriravishankar.org/feed/) did show short descriptions ending with "..."?

Comment: Yes asantaballa...It shows complete description but while fetching it using SAX parser it is showing me indention whereas i am nowhere suppressing content in code !! Howcome that ?

Comment: Ahh, not sure if this will help. If I look at the _source_ of the RSS feed (view source option in browser), I see the two distinct XML fields. <description> which contains the short description. and <content:encoded> which contains the full text. Not sure how your code is reading it but id you ask for the alternate field yo should get the full text.

<description><![CDATA[Once upon a time, a Guru ... with only part of the text 
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Once upon a time, a Guru … with all the text

Comment: Thanks asantaballa. Is there any way to fetch this <content:encoded> tag ? I am editing my question and pasting code there. I tried but it returns NULL POINTER

Comment: asataballa :- It won't work. I tried "qname" as well as "localName". I guess this is drawback in SAX parser. If i use DOM it will work.

Comment: Damn, sorry. One last thought before giving up. One of the differences between the SAX and DOM parsers is that he SAX can only read in order because it does not load the entire file at once. Maybe if you want to try one more thing, make sue your tags are in the order coming in on the file. Also try (for now) removing the tags that are not there like "content" and "media:content"

Good luck :-(

Comment: Thanks asantaballa. I could make it happen using DOM Parser.